# I cant run php container because of OCI runtime create failed

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, devops, docker-container

> Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "php-fpm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

I want to containerize wordpress with Docker. I want my dockerfiles to be based on ubuntu (I know that I could just use some php image and it would be worked because I already tried it). Here is my Dockerfile and docker-compose file:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y php && \
    apt-get install -y php-mysql && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/sbin/

CMD ["php-fpm", "-F"]

version: "3.9"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25.3-alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp
      MYSQL_USER: wp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

Comment: If I do install the same packages as your PHP image and try to run `php-fpm`, I get `bash: php-fpm: command not found`, so, yes, this is expected. Why don't you use the existing `php:fpm` image instead?

Comment: FWIIW, the `php-fpmX.Y` binary can be found in the `phpX.Y-fpm` package, e.g. [php8.1-fpm](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=php-fpm&mode=filename&suite=jammy&arch=any).

Comment: I just got an exercise to do this in this way. I know how to do this with php:fpm image, because I already did it and now I'm trying to do this with ubuntu

Comment: Hey, I found a solution. I created a temporary image, connected to it, and located the file. It was in this location, but its exact name is: php-fpm8.1.